# Is it possible to create smart contracts on Graphene?

Tags: bitshares

I can't found any article on this, is it possible to create smart contracts inside the [BitShares](https://bitshares.org/technology/)' blockchain Graphene?

This is my necessity:

1. I have to allow my users to purchase my products via [SmartCoins](https://bitshares.org/technology/price-stable-cryptocurrencies/).
2. Users must wait for a confirmation (bank signature needed)
3. Issuance of certificate of ownership

Comment: Bitcoin Stack Exchange on topic seems to have changed; sorry if migrated incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphene smart contracts are blockchain wide, meaning they require a hardfork to be deployed. The reasoning behind this is that every node operator can review the contract code, ok it and then democratically vote by joining the hardfork.

It's kind of a hassle compared to ETH/ETC but that provides a few choices of very well tested contracts.

OpenLedger has proposed an enhancement to BTS that would provide a VM like EthereumVM and allow users to easily deploy smartcontracts. It's still under discussion: https://bitsharestalk.org/index.php?topic=25187.0